# Creating new instance of object implementing Mappable interface

Tags: swift, swift3, objectmapper

I am using [ObjectMapper library](https://github.com/Hearst-DD/ObjectMapper) to convert my model objects (classes and structs) to and from JSON.

But sometimes I would like to create objects without JSON.

Supposse, I have class like this:

```
class User: Mappable {
    var username: String?
    var age: Int?

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        username    <- map["username"]
        age         <- map["age"]
    } 
}
```

I would like to create object without JSON, like this:

```
let newUser = User(username: "john", age: 18)
```

Is creating objects in this way possible for class implementing *Mappable*?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Add another init method with username and age as parameters.

```
class User: Mappable {
    var username: String?
    var age: Int?

    init(username:String, age:Int) {
        self.username = username
        self.age = age
    }

    required init?(map: Map) {

    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        username    <- map["username"]
        age         <- map["age"]
    }
}
```

And use it like this.

```
let user = User(username: "hello", age: 34)
```